# The \titlepage problem in beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

When I put in the preamble. It has several warning as

> Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode)

Because I use the `$^1$` in the title.

Then when I put in the document. the warning appears. How do I solve it? Thanks

> Option `pdfauthor' has already been used

My MWE

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\aleph$}


\title[Cross]{\large Experimental Studies %
\thanks{\scriptsize Project supported by foundation:  Supported by the National Nature Science Foundation}}
\author[A,B,C]{A$^1$,
B$^1$
and C$^2$}
\institute[Fluid Mechanics]{$^1$Department of Mechanics \& Engineering Science\\
$^2$College of Science}
\date[The second presentation, 2013]{The second presentation, 2013}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=16pt]{picture/Fudanlog.PNG}}
\date[\initclock\tdtime]{\today}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title1}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle1}
  Some text s
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no error with your code, but rather a style issue, see my answer below. Regarding the error, there might some outdated TeX distribution?

Comment: Addendum to my comment above: I should have written 'warning' instead of 'error', since the messages you mentioned indicate warnings but not errors.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I means `warning` but write `error`. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `\inst{number}` command within `beamer` to indicate the institution an author comes frome instead of using mathematical superscripts.

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{$\aleph$}


\title[Cross]{\large Experimental Studies %
\thanks{\scriptsize Project supported by foundation:  Supported by the National Nature Science Foundation}}
\author[A,B,C]{A\inst{1}  \and B\inst{2}  \and C\inst{2}}

% Old style
%\author[A,B,C]{A$^1$,
%B$^1$
%and C$^2$}
\institute[Fluid Mechanics]{$^1$Department of Mechanics \& Engineering Science\\
$^2$College of Science}
\date[The second presentation, 2013]{The second presentation, 2013}
%\logo{\includegraphics[height=16pt]{picture/Fudanlog.PNG}}
\date[\initclock\tdtime]{\today}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title1}
  \framesubtitle{frame subtitle1}
  Some text s
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit** My screenshot is cropped at the top, just for reducing the size.

[image]

Comment: It works, :-D. Thanks for helping.

Comment: using this MWE still I have a warning: `Package hyperref Warning: Option 'pdfauthor' has already been used, setting the option has no effect on input line 12.`

Comment: For people have the same problem as [`Bilal`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/203810/bilal), consider [his question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/647802).