# How to add a picture on video using movie15 package or media9 or multimedia package(s) on LinuxOS

Tags: beamer, media9, movie15, includegraphics

I have been experimenting with the sample of code from [LaTeX beamer presentation](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Movie_pdf). At this point let me clarify that I know that this is a deprecated module and that I should be using [media9](https://ctan.org/pkg/media9) and not [movie15](https://ctan.org/pkg/movie15), but I have spend 2 days trying to make it work with all these configurations but none of the sample of codes that I found online worked for me e.g. [How to include multimedia files in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345431/how-to-include-multimedia-files-in-beamer/345433#345433) or [Embedding Videos in LaTeX Beamer](https://youjiexia.github.io/2017/02/15/Embedding-Video-Files-in-Latex-Beamer/) or [Using media9 to include videos files](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/using-media9-to-include-videos-files/yvdwwvpknjkk#.WrKLt3XwZhE) or [Video in a Presentation](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24531) etc...etc...so I gave up on the idea and switched to the deprecated module.

Sample of working code from [LaTeX beamer presentation](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Movie_pdf) slightly modified:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[3D]{movie15}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% \usepackage{hyperref} % update based on comments
\usepackage{graphicx}

%% See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations
%% See: http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/
\usetheme{Copenhagen} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Thanos},
  pdftitle={Simple Beamer Class},
  pdfsubject={Subject},
  pdfkeywords={Key} {Words} {List},
  urlcolor=blue,
}
\author{Thanos} % updating based on comments

\begin{document}
\title{Simple Beamer Class}   
% \author{Thanos}
\date{\today} 
\frame{\titlepage} 
\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents} 

\section{Movie} 
\frame{\frametitle{Pymol Movie object}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includemovie[
poster,
toolbar, %same as `controls'
text={\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{samplePicture.eps}}
% text={\phantom{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{samplePicture.eps}}} % update based on comments
]{10cm}{6cm}{SampleVideo.mp4}
\caption{A PyMOL movie object embedded in PDF, using mpg format.}
\label{mov:ex3d}
\end{figure}
}

\section{Lists}
\subsection{Lists I}
\frame{\frametitle{Unnumbered lists}
\begin{block}{My bloc}
test of bloc
\end{block}

\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction to  \LaTeX  
\item Beamer class
\end{itemize} 
}
\end{document}
```

My question is how to add a picture on the video. Based on the documentation of the package [The movie15 Package](http://ftp.cvut.cz/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/movie15/doc/movie15.pdf) page 6 shows that we can add a picture with the following part `text={\phantom{\includegraphics[scale=2]{path/to/poster}}}`.

After compiling the code is working and the video is playing but the picture is not displayed is there any workaround this problem?

A minor note to make here, I am also getting this error:

`hyperref: Option 'pdfauthor' has already been used,`

I searched online and I found this thread [The \titlepage problem in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174776/the-titlepage-problem-in-beamer), the proposed solution did not work for me, or [How to get rid of those beamer warnings](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/latex-general/beamer-warnings/), or [Errors with Beamer not understandable](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10157). This is not something important I know this is only a warning but since I am asking the question why not trying to resolve all of my questions.

**Update:**

I forgot to include my Latex version:

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.41.0
```

**Update2**

Adding video.log file, download here ([video.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ityscvn7grzj2wt/video.log?dl=0)).

**Update3**

Sample of output based on comment (removing `\phantom`).

[image: Output]

**Update4**

Sample of code for package [media9](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%% See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations
%% See: http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/
\usetheme{Copenhagen} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Thanos},
  pdftitle={This is the title},
  pdfsubject={Pdf Subject},
  pdfkeywords={Key} {Words} {List},
  urlcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}

\title{Sample of media9 attempt}
\date{\today} 
\frame{\titlepage} 
\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents}  

\section{Movie} 
\frame{\frametitle{Movie using media9}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\includemedia[
  %activate=onclick, % default
  addresource=sampleVideo.mp4,
  flashvars={
    source=sampleVideo.mp4
    &autoPlay=true % start playing on activation
    &loop=true
  },
  passcontext %show player's right-click menu
]{\includegraphics[height=0.45\linewidth]{samplePicture.eps}}{VPlayer9.swf}
\caption{A media9 package movie embedded in PDF, using mp4 format.}
\label{mov:ex3d}
\end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Adding video.log file, download here ([videoMedia9.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mg9jzmp5vqaxw6s/videoMedia9.log?dl=0)).

Comment: The warning - not error - `hyperref: Option 'pdfauthor' has already been used` is caused by using `\author` after `\begin{document}`.  Use it before if you want to avoid the warning.

Comment: You don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer.

Comment: If you'd use `\author` etc. before `\begin{document}` you would not need `\hypersetup{...}`

Comment: Using `[!htb]` in a document class without floats does not make sense. Figures are centred by default in beamer, so `\centering` is unnecessary.

Comment: Back to your actual problem: can you please add the log file from your MWE?

Comment: @samcarter, Thanks for the comments see my update to the log file.

Comment: Can you try without `\phantom`?

Comment: Why didn't you post a question about your `media9`-related problem?

Comment: @samcarter I have update the code and also removed the `\phantom` see my update and also screen shot of the output now.

Comment: @AlexG To be honest I read and tried so many, so many samples of working code that I end up believing that my latex version was the problem. I was running 2012 before, so I decide to update the version try again and again and nothing worked. So I gave up since everyone says that is working it does not work for my PC I guess. I can raise a question again but I do not know if it will work at the end or not.

Comment: This may well be the reason for the failure. Did you try to install current TeXLive-2017 into your User directory? You can safely do this in parallel to the already intsalled but outdated system-wide installation If you adjust the PATH correctly. Which TeX installation do you use currently?

Comment: I see from your post you are using TeXLive-2017 shipping with Debian. TL-2017 is frozen now (until TL-18 release). Can you try to update all installed packages to their last TL-17 version before freezing?

Comment: @AlexG Thanks for the follow up. It looks my repo is up to date:

`$ tlmgr update --all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: no updates available`

Comment: Could you add the code example using `media9` to your question? Put `\listfiles` on its top, run `pdflatex` and post the file list from the `*.log` as well.

Comment: @AlexG, Thanks for the idea of `\listfiles` see the update. The pdf contains the picture but it does not play the video. So I am bit lost on why. This is why I switched to the movie15 package.

Comment: Which PDF viewer do you use (You need Acrobat Reader for `media9`, sorry. On Linux there is no AR available anymore; you could try running AR for Windows inside Wine)?

Comment: @AlexG, I assumed the same. In the past I used Okular with movie15 and still working fine. As you correctly identified I was still using it, so I was reading online why is not working so I download it the latest Acrobat for linux. No I am getting the error `A 3D data parsing error has occurred`. Trying to get more information on how to fix this problem.

Comment: The last AR for Linux with embedded FlashPlayer was 9.4.1, After that Adobe dropped Flash support in AR f. Linux. Flash is needed for the video playback method that `media9` implements. (Still being AR's standard.)

Comment: @AlexG, I tried with Adobe 9.4.1, I am not getting the error but I am getting the error of not loading the video. I found an alternative solution with multimedia module. I will post complete code as an answer including all the findings so people in future can benefit. Thanks a lot for the analytical guide and follow up on my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1053/alexg) guidance and expertise he helped me to understand that [okular](https://okular.kde.org) is not enough to play multimedia from [media9](https://ctan.org/pkg/media9). Proposed solution with [Adobe Reader unix 9.4.1](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.4.1/) unfortunately for me is not working.

Output of not loading the video from sample of code provided above with [media9](https://ctan.org/pkg/media9) package:

[image: AdobeReader]

So the only solution that worked for my simple requirements is to use `\usepackage{multimedia}`.

Sample of working code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% \usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
% \usepackage{graphicx}

%% See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations
%% See: http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/
\usetheme{Copenhagen} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Thanos},
  pdftitle={This is the title},
  pdfsubject={Pdf Subject},
  pdfkeywords={Key} {Words} {List},
  urlcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}
  \title{Sample of multimedia attempt}
  \date{\today}
  \frame{\titlepage}
  \frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents}    

  \section{Movie} 
    \begin{frame}{Movie using media9}
      \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \movie[label=show3,%
               width=1.0\textwidth,%
               poster,%
               % autostart,%
               showcontrols,%
               % loop,%
              ]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]
               {samplePicture.eps}}
               {sampleVideo.mp4}
        \caption{A media9 package movie embedded in PDF, using mp4 format.}
      \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
    \label{mov:show3}
\end{document}
```

Similar question that the solution has been accepted with [media9](https://ctan.org/pkg/media9) package [Did anyone succeed in playing embedded movies inside Acrobat in Linux?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed-in-playing-embedded-movies-inside-acrobat-in-linux) maybe for someone else the sample of code might work.

Comment: As for the `media9` example, It seems there is an issue with the encoding of your `SampleVideo.mp4`. Could you try e. g. [↗`cube.mp4`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/files/cube.mp4) coming with the `media9` pkg instead?

Comment: @AlexG Unfortunately same output. Hmmm this is getting strange, I followed the instructions from here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-in-debian) the installation looks correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexG I run the acroread from the terminal to see what is happening in the background. When the acroread starts I get:

`$ acroread videoMedia9.pdf `
`Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"`
`Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"`

As soon as I press the play button on the pdf I get: `(acroread:5712): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_user_time called on non-toplevel`.

I tried to search online regarding the last error that seems to be related to my problem but unfortunately nothing related to Linux and Acrobat Reader together.

Comment: Could you please put `sampleVideo.mp4` into Dropbox (for testing, if you don't mind)?

Comment: @AlexG, Sure I can share the demo video in Dropbox the file that I am using is open in public. You can download the file from here (http://www.sample-videos.com). I have chosen the smallest file, but feel free to test with any if you think that the size is important. Let me know if you require any further information.

Comment: On my Linux box, AR-9.4.1 doesn't start at all, incompatible libraries perhaps. Did you try the documentation file [↗`media9.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf)? The examples on page 29 (and only these!) should work in AR-9.4.1.

Comment: @AlexG You are right, it worked I was missing the Adobe Flash player. The problem is that there is no sound through this player.